# OpenWRT backported ath11k can't find backported dependencies at build time

Tags: linux, openwrt, backport

I am attempting to backport `ath11k` support for kernel 5.4 on OpenWRT 21.02 (updating is outside my control). I am specifically after the `ath11k_pci` module which has dependencies on `hwmon`, `qmi_helpers`, `mhi`, and `qrtr`. So far I've managed to achieve the following:

- Direct package `mac80211` to utilize backports from 5.15.74-1 instead of 5.10.100-1
- Patch kernel 5.4 to remove `ARCH_QCOM` dependency from `qmi_helpers` and `qrtr` modules.
- Register the entry for the following backports in the main `menuconfig`:

  - added `kmod-ath1k` and removed the `@TARGET_ipq807x` dependency (ath.mk)
  - added `kmod-qrtr`, `kmod-mhi-net`, and `kmod-mhi` as those are backported from 5.15.74-1 (other.mk, netsupport.mk, netdevices.mk)

Once I've selected the `kmod` options added to `menuconfig`, the `kernel_menuconfig` is called and compiles the toolchain. It applies the patches I've made to enable the subsets of `CONFIG_QMI_HELPERS` and `CONFIG_QRTR`, then I just set them as `=y`. Note: the backported kernel modules do not show up as options in the `kernel_menuconfig`.

Finally I call `make V=s` and after a couple of minutes or so I get the following error:

```
Package kmod-ath11k is missing dependencies for the following libraries:
mhi.ko
```

When I `find` for the module, I can see it compiled successfully and it is located under the backports directory for my target:
`.../backports-5.15.74-1/drivers/bus/mhi/core/mhi.ko`

So my issue is that `kmod-ath11k` fails to compile because it can't find `mhi.ko` when it clearly gets compiled. I have specified the `kmod` to explicitly depend on the aforementioned kmods but it still fails and I cannot determine where else this dependency has to be registered.

---

This is the current `ath11k` definition under `package/kernel/mac8021/ath.mk`

```
define KernelPackage/ath11k
  $(call KernelPackage/mac80211/Default)
  TITLE:=Qualcomm 802.11ax wireless chipset support
  URL:=https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath11k
  DEPENDS+= @PCI_SUPPORT +kmod-ath +@DRIVER_11N_SUPPORT +@DRIVER_11AC_SUPPORT +@DRIVER_11AX_SUPPORT \
            +kmod-crypto-michael-mic +kmod-qrtr-mhi +kmod-mhi-bus +kmod-mhi-net
  FILES:= \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath11k/ath11k.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath11k/ath11k_pci.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,ath11k ath11k_pci)
endef
```

this is the `mhi-bus` definition under `package/kernel/linux/modules/other.mk`

```
define KernelPackage/mhi-bus
  SUBMENU:=$(OTHER_MENU)
  TITLE:=Modem Host Interface (MHI) bus and PCI driver
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_MHI_BUS=y \
           CONFIG_MHI_BUS_PCI_GENERIC \
           CONFIG_MHI_BUS_DEBUG=y
  FILES:=$(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/bus/mhi/mhi_pci_generic.ko \
         $(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/bus/mhi/core/mhi.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,mhi mhi_pci_generic)
endef

define KernelPackage/mhi-bus/description
  Kernel modules for the Qualcoom MHI bus.
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,mhi-bus))
```

definition for `qrtr` under `package/kernel/linux/modules/netsupport.mk`

```
define KernelPackage/qrtr
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_SUPPORT_MENU)
  TITLE:=Qualcomm IPC Router support
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_QRTR
  FILES:= \
  $(LINUX_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,qrtr)
endef

define KernelPackage/qrtr/description
 Qualcomm IPC Router support
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,qrtr))

define KernelPackage/qrtr-tun
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_SUPPORT_MENU)
  TITLE:=TUN device for Qualcomm IPC Router
  DEPENDS:=+kmod-qrtr
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_QRTR_TUN
  FILES:= $(LINUX_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr-tun.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,qrtr-tun)
endef

define KernelPackage/qrtr-tun/description
 TUN device for Qualcomm IPC Router
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,qrtr-tun))

define KernelPackage/qrtr-smd
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_SUPPORT_MENU)
  TITLE:=SMD IPC Router channels
  DEPENDS:=+kmod-qrtr @TARGET_ipq807x
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_QRTR_SMD
  FILES:= $(LINUX_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr-smd.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,qrtr-smd)
endef

define KernelPackage/qrtr-smd/description
 SMD IPC Router channels
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,qrtr-smd))

define KernelPackage/qrtr-mhi
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_SUPPORT_MENU)
  TITLE:=MHI IPC Router channels
  DEPENDS:=+kmod-mhi-bus +kmod-qrtr
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_QRTR_MHI
  FILES:= $(LINUX_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr-mhi.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,qrtr-mhi)
endef

define KernelPackage/qrtr-mhi/description
 MHI IPC Router channels
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,qrtr-mhi))
```

and definition for `mhi-net` under `package/kernel/linux/modules/netdevices.mk`

```
define KernelPackage/mhi-net
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_DEVICES_MENU)
  TITLE:=MHI Network Device
  DEPENDS:=@PCI_SUPPORT +kmod-mhi-bus
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_MHI_NET
  FILES:=$(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/net/mhi_net.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,mhi_net)
endef

define KernelPackage/mhi-net/description
  Driver for MHI network interface
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,mhi-net))

define KernelPackage/wwan
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_DEVICES_MENU)
  TITLE:=WWAN Driver Core
  DEPENDS:=@PCI_SUPPORT
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_WWAN
  FILES:=$(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/net/wwan/wwan.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,wwan)
endef

define KernelPackage/wwan/description
  The WWAN core driver provides a common framework for WWAN drivers.
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,wwan))

define KernelPackage/mhi-wwan-ctrl
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_DEVICES_MENU)
  TITLE:=MHI WWAN control driver for QCOM-based PCIe modems
  DEPENDS:=@PCI_SUPPORT +kmod-wwan +kmod-mhi-net
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_MHI_WWAN_CTRL
  FILES:=$(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/net/wwan/mhi_wwan_ctrl.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,mhi_wwan_ctrl)
endef

define KernelPackage/mhi-wwan-ctrl/description
  MHI WWAN CTRL allows QCOM-based PCIe modems to expose different modem
  control protocols/ports to userspace, including AT, MBIM, QMI, DIAG
  and FIREHOSE. These protocols can be accessed directly from userspace
  (e.g. AT commands) or via libraries/tools (e.g. libmbim, libqmi,
  libqcdm...).
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,mhi-wwan-ctrl))

define KernelPackage/mhi-wwan-mbim
  SUBMENU:=$(NETWORK_DEVICES_MENU)
  TITLE:=MHI WWAN MBIM network driver for QCOM-based PCIe modems
  DEPENDS:=@PCI_SUPPORT +kmod-wwan +kmod-mhi-net
  KCONFIG:=CONFIG_MHI_WWAN_MBIM
  FILES:=$(LINUX_DIR)/drivers/net/wwan/mhi_wwan_mbim.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,mhi_wwan_mbim)
endef

define KernelPackage/mhi-wwan-mbim/description
  MHI WWAN MBIM is a WWAN network driver for QCOM-based PCIe modems.
  It implements MBIM over MHI, for IP data aggregation and muxing.
  A default wwan0 network interface is created for MBIM data session
  ID 0. Additional links can be created via wwan rtnetlink type.
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,mhi-wwan-mbim))
```

Comment: maybe have a look at dependencies listed here https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/openwrt/patch/20211024194209.521400-2-janusz.dziedzic@gmail.com/#2775202

Comment: @stark Thanks! After reviewing the commit, it seems to be a much cleaner implementation from what I've done. I did compare the kernel package options and there seems to not be a big difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial and error I gained some understanding of my implementation and was able to fix my issue.

First of all, I had to understand my specific case, where I'm backporting 5.15 modules onto a 5.4 kernel toolchain. The `kmod` options I added to the main `menuconfig` (with the exception of `ath11k`) are directly dealing with the options offered by the toolchain kernel (5.4) and not the bakcport kernel modules (5.15), and since those were not present in this specific kernel version I would get the error I stated in my original post. Thanks to [stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark) for pointing me to this [patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/openwrt/patch/20211024194209.521400-2-janusz.dziedzic@gmail.com/#2775202)

In addition to this, if I set `CONFIG_QMI_HELPERS` or `CONFIG_HWMON` to `=m` instead `=y` in the toolchain kernel, the backport build mechanism wouldn't be able to see the `.ko` files because those were in a different directory from where the backport process is happening.

At this point I realized I was compiling a frankestein `ath11k` with intertwined 5.4 and 5.15 dependecies, fortunately checking the modules offered by the backports made me realize a lot of the dependencies are also backported too, so I figured out how to point the the `ath11k` to these in `ath.mk` and get as many dependencies as possible from the backports. So in turn I got rid of all the other additions I made to the other `.mk` files and used this definition for `KernelPackage/ath11k`

```
define KernelPackage/ath11k
  $(call KernelPackage/mac80211/Default)
  TITLE:=Qualcomm 802.11ax wireless chipset support
  URL:=https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath11k
  DEPENDS+= @PCI_SUPPORT +kmod-ath +@DRIVER_11N_SUPPORT +@DRIVER_11AC_SUPPORT +@DRIVER_11AX_SUPPORT \
        +kmod-crypto-michael-mic
  FILES:= \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath11k/ath11k.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath11k/ath11k_pci.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/bus/mhi/core/mhi.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/net/qrtr/ns.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/net/qrtr/qrtr-mhi.ko \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/drivers/soc/qcom/qmi_helpers.ko
  AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoProbe,ath11k ath11k_pci)
endef

define KernelPackage/ath11k/description
This module adds support for Qualcomm Technologies 802.11ax family of
chipsets.
endef
```

Note: I also had to set `CONFIG_HWMON=y` in my toolchain kernel to workaround the issue mentioned above.

Apologies if what I state here is erroneous in some way, this is the first time I've ever dealt with backports on OpenWRT, but definitively let me know if anything I said here can be corrected/improved :D